# Ruby performance issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance

I am running into a problem these past following weeks.
The problem is that ruby performance is absolutely horrible.

Attached is a screenshot of newrelic, check out the performance of ruby.
[image]

I am running ruby 1.8.7, Rails 2.3.

My main problem is that Ruby is really taking lots of time to process, more than the DB, more than Membase and more than anything else happening on the server.

What can cause this issue?
how can I fix it?

Edit #1: Changed the screenshot
Added some description.

Comment: Well I can't imagine how anyone could answer such a vague question.  Show us the code that encapsulates your bottleneck.

Comment: What are the units on the y axis?

Comment: @chris the units are milliseconds

Comment: This could be caused by anything, and it's not even clear if Ruby is the problem here. What if you have no indexes on your database? What if your database isn't even tuned properly? What if you're out of memory?

Comment: @tadman ruby is the bottom layer, database is the orange layer, membase is the blue layer and solr is the green layer.

Ruby is taking the most time to process so I am wondering why it'a happening.

Comment: @Ed S. I changed the image, added some description as for my problem.

Comment: Run ruby-prof http://ruby-prof.rubyforge.org/

Comment: You say "the past following weeks". Do you mean that Ruby performance _used_ to be good and has gotten worse? Do you have performance logs to show this?

Comment: A possible fix would be to upgrade to ruby 1.9, rails 3.

Comment: What template system are you using for your views? Haml, Erb, other?

Comment: In future, consider either (1) Just asking for useful resources on diagnosing performance issues or (2) Narrowing down the question to something specific.

Answer (score 2):

Basically what you're asking is:

> My code is slow. How can I make it
>   faster?

without providing any detail of what is that your code does.It's impossible to give an acceptable answer to that question.

Anyway I'd like to point out that 1.8.7 (I assume MRI) is the slowest version of ruby around today.  You might wanna check 1.9.2 that uses the new VM (YARV) or even JRuby's VM which is faster too.

Comment: [Kiji](http://engineering.twitter.com/2011/03/building-faster-ruby-garbage-collector.html) is the performance-tuned version of 1.8.7, so that's worth checking out too.

Comment: Kiji is not as mature I believe, but thanks for pointing it out! :)

Answer (score 2):

The updated chart is better, but still provides only marginally more than zero information on what the problem might be. You'll have to dig deeper into your application to find out what's taking so long to process.

Using something like [ruby-prof](http://rubyforge.org/projects/ruby-prof/) would help narrow down your problem, but it's not especially effective in a production environment.

When tackling a problem like this, the first thing I do is start turning off things in the application, stripping it down to a very basic, nearly "hello world" state, then enable them systematically and look for a big spike in load times.

When it comes to tuning Ruby applications you should be very careful not to generate a lot of garbage, as the big weakness in any garbage-collected language is leaving a lot of trash laying around.

Ideally you should be retrieving as little data as possible as required to load the page, which often means bypassing models entirely, and should use the most efficient representation possible. As life is never ideal, the best we can hope to do is move towards this goal in increments.

I see patterns all the time where people will want to display a list of user names and in the controller there's something like this:

```
@users = @group.users.all
```

The side-effect of this is loading in each user's extended biography, which could be a serious chunk of HTML, as well as fifty other fields that you will never use before trashing those objects.

A smarter move is to strip this right down, then, if applicable, cache it:

```
@users = @group.users.select([ :id, :name ])
```

You can even go further and just use the `connection` directly with things like `select_values` but that's a more involved approach.

To get to the bottom of your performance problem pay very close attention to your logs. If practical, run your production server in `debug` level logging for a reasonable period of time, and then have a close look at the times on queries, view rendering, or any other place that might stand out as being slow.